# complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

does $\ f(z) = e^{z^2} $ have an antiderivative in the whole complex plane?

I think it does not but  I am having trouble explaining why.

Since e is differentiable everywhere in the complex plane but zero, wouldn't it work the same for anti derivatives ?

Comment: It does have an antiderivative ... it just cannot be expressed in terms of "elementary" functions.

Comment: It's not too much work to find its Taylor polynomial, though. Just insert $z^2$ into the Taylor polynomial of the exponential function and then differentiate.

Comment: $e^{z^2}$ is analytic everywhere, if that is your question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, we have $$e^{z^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{z^{2n}}{n!}.$$ Hence, the antiderivative exists and is given by $$z\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}.$$ Here we have used holomorphicity to compute the antiderivative term by term.